# How to read and list a tgz file in python3?

Tags: python, gzip, tar

In python 3 (3.6.8) I want to read a gzipped tar file and list its content.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858414/using-python-how-do-you-untar-purely-in-memory) which yields an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Searching for this error in found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659851/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8b-in-position-1-invalid/44660123) so I tried the following code snippet:

```
with open(out_file) as fd:
    gzip_fd = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fd)
    tar = tarfile.open(gzip_fd.read())
```

which yields the same error!

So how to do it right?

Even when looking at the actual documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) I came up with the following code:

```
tar = tarfile.open(out_file, "w:gz")
for member in tar.getnames():
   print(tar.extractfile(member).read())
```

which finally worked without errors - but did not print any content of the tar archive on the screen!

The tar file is well formatted and contains folders and files. (I need to try to share this file)

Comment: What is the output of `tar -ztvf <TGZ-FILENAME>.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it did not work before, but the following solution works for me in order to **list the files and folders of a gzipped tar archive with python 3.6**:

```
tar = tarfile.open(filename, "r:gz")
print(tar.getnames())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `open` a file without specifying `mode` it defaults to reading it as text. You need to open the file as raw byte stream using `mode='rb'` flag then feed it to gzip reader

```py
with open(out_file, mode='rb') as fd:
    gzip_fd = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fd)
    tar = tarfile.open(gzip_fd.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

The python-archive module (available on pip) could help you:

```py
from archive import extract

file = "you/file.tgz"
try:
    extract(file, "out/%s.raw" % (file), ext=".tgz")
except:
    # could not extract
    pass
```

Available extensions are (v0.2): '.zip', '.egg', '.jar', '.tar', '.tar.gz', '.tgz', '.tar.bz2', '.tz2'

More info: https://pypi.org/project/python-archive/