# python3 - urllib - ssl - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib2, urllib3

I want to run this code. But error why is it error?

```
import requests
import ssl
from urllib import request

urlMain = "https://www.example.com/"
urlLogin = "https://www.example.com/join/"

istekBaba = requests.get(urlMain)
cookies = istekBaba.cookies.get_dict()
baslik = {
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site" :"none",
    "Accept" : "text/html",
    "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
    "Referer" : "https://www.example.com/"
}

req = request.Request(url=urlLogin,headers=baslik)
req.add_header("Cookie","ud_rule_vars"+"="+cookies["ud_rule_vars"]+";")
contextssl = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
res = request.urlopen(req,context=contextssl)
with res as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Why it is error?

Error code is here

```
C:\Users\emRe\Documents\works\python\test>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

error why is error? what is wrong?
thank you guys for helping....

edit: 
if delete utf-8, i see it.

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe2\xb2I\xc9,SH\xceI,.\xb6U\xca\xc9O\xcf\xccK\xca\xaf\xd0-3Q\xc8\xcd\x07\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x9cV\xdfS\xe36\x10~\xcf_\xa1\xea\xe1x\xa9p`\xca\xaf\xbb\xc4L\xb9\xbb^\xb92\x1cS\xa0\xed\xb5\xd3\xc9\xc8\xd6\xc6\x16\x91\xb5B\x96I2\x9d\xfe\xef\x1dYvb\x87\xc0A\xf3\x10\xdb+\xed\xf7\xed~\xab\x95$\xb8b)j\x07\xda\xb1\xb9\xe5\xc6\x80%\x95`\xdc\x18\xa6\x90\x8b\xf0\x95baP\xfb)\xac\xc4Tr\xc5x\xe5r\xe6g\xd1\x01i\x7f\x82;\xce\n\x14\x95\x02&\xc5\x98v\xa6>1\x8b\xdb\xac\x1c\xd3\x7f\xde\xdcW\xe8\xde\x15( \xbc\xbd\r\x8f\x8b/\x9f\xce/\xc3\xeb\xbf\x9b\x00\xa6\xb2\x06Kh\xb2a\t.h<\xe8f\xf9\\\xd4\xfe\xbf\x04\xd0,Y\xb2\xaa\x04\xcb\x9c\xe5\xe9\x0c,\x8dG\x91\x90\x0f}\xa0\x8e\\\x93I\x0e^\x12\x1a\x0f.0#\xe7\x9a8$_\xb1\xb2\xe4V@\xb1$?\xa6)V\xda}7\xf8\x16L#\xb8\x0f\xb94\\wb~R\xf7G\x82o\xaa\xdd\x95\xf9I\x8d\xb91\n\xae\x1dw}\xa5\xc1Vy\x9a\xdc\xe5\xe5b\xa6\x8a\xc5b\x11\xac\xdfw|\xde+\t\xda\x9d\x8b\x9e[\x8a\xc5n\xe53\xdf\x9dC\xd2\xf3\xc9\x10\xb3\'\x9c\x8e\x86\xc3\xfd\xe1\xe1p\x7fo8<`\xc9\xd4\x82\x1e\xde\xdf\xed\xa1=6\xe6\xa04Z\x1f\xec\xef\xe5X\x9e\xa8\xe2D\xa9\x93]nL\xb9\x1b\xd0|\xa5\x1a\xe1vS,\xfa1*\x85s\x10\xd7u\x99\xcf*\xe7P\x97\r\xeb_\xe19\xe5)$\x88\xb3-a2\xa3\xaa\xf2q\xca\xe1\xf5\xef\xae\xe9W\x10\xd2B\xean\xad\xec\xe5\x94;g\xca\xb7Q4\x9f\xcf\x1bAR,\xa2;\x94:jV\x9e\xaf\xa4\x02\x07Q\x8d\x13\xd5\xab!\xeaq\xb6\x01\xae9T\x8f\xa3\x07\x97\x80\xf7o]\xa2\xd3\xa9\xc5b\\\x83\xbe\xe1\x85y\'di\x14_N\xdc\xd2\xc0\xd8\xa0\xa9LmV\x98r\x05c\xd0\x93\xdb\xeb-:\xbc\x88y\x95HG\xbb\xe8\xf4\xb5\x84<u\x12\xf5\xcd\xd2\xf4\xd7a\xc8\xa0\xdf\xf1\xdd\xb5l\xacD+\xddrL\xd9\xfe\xd0wO\xe4\xdb\'\x1e\x8c\xa6h\x0bB\x02\xea\x98>S\x8e\xb0]\xd4\x11\xbe(j\xda\x80\xb2zN\xe8b\xda\xf6k)3-5\xab\xc9\xc5\x1d%\xbe\r\x03\x817Q\xa2y\x01}K\x01.G1\xa6\x06KGILFR\x9b\xca\x91\x1a|\'\x97B\x80\xde\tn;ii\xa7\x85\x14B\xc1\x9c[p8\xf3C\x0f\\U~\xe6\x17}\xff\xe9\xf2su\xf8\xfbr\xaf<;\xb8\xfe\xe5\xe8\xec\xf6\xfa\xcf\x0b\xa3\xaf2s\x979\x10\x7f|UG\x1f\xf2\xe3\xd9\xb19L\xd2\x93\x8b\x9b\xe5\xfe\xde\xcf\x97{\xef\xef\xcfo>\xdb\xdf\x8e\x16;$\x8aI\xbd;\x91Z\xe5&\x9f\x82k\x9e\x01\x9bJP\xa2lO\x83\xcd0i\x083\x94\xa7\xcd\xd0\x0b\x16,!B\x1a\xc4\xab-\xeb\xbf\x96\xb4\xa1\xf3\x92\x04\xb2\xfa\x04\xe2R\x83%D\xf1\x04\x14\x88\xe7\x8e\x1dq\xc7u\x86\x0c\n.U\x00\x08L^\xff\x1aT:(\xc2p\x18\x88\xc9\xa8\x86m\x99=\x9dE\xc5\x82\x91\x92)\xda1\x95b\x12\\\xe2\x8f\xfe1\x8a\xea\xd1&d\x0f\xed\x10\x95\x93\x86Y\x98\x82\x05\x9dB\x97\xa2#\xe3\xa3y\xc4`\xc9,\xa1\x1bB\x06\xefF\xc3\xe6\xa3\xe0\x0b\x05:s\xf9\x98\x1e\xfe\x10V\xd4*\xae\x16\xbf\xfe\n@u\xb6M6\x94X\xb8\xaf\xa4\x05A\x8c\xe2)\xe4\xa8\x04\xd81\xfd\xd8 K\xdd"\x1f\xd1\x8dC\xb4\xc1\xf7\xf5iN\xae\xfa\xf1\x8ajm+\x80\xe1e9G+^W\x83\x95W|\xd5\xbc\xbd\xa4\x12}\xae\xffQ\x8c\x15@S\x8f\xf5\xf7\xf6\x92\xac\xc7["X\xb8\x06\x10\x16\xee|KyzU\xb9Z\xf9\xaf\xaa\xd6\xa9\xd0\xe1f\x85\xd6t\x9bE\xdav\xd9\xa8y\xc3\xc6U\xd2m\x9d^VI!\x1d\xb38\x7f\xd4\xdea\xa8\xdb\xde]K\xd3\xde\xe1\xfa\xd3\xe9\xef\x0ev\xe24I\x9c\xf6\x9bu\xc1\xed\x92\xacKR_\n\x03\xb3\x14\xac\x0b;\xd8r\xb3\x13\xc8\xc2v\xdb\xec\x1d\xe1\xae\x14\xa3%\xcd\xb6?\xe2$\xb70\x1d\xd3\xc8_\r\xa2)\xda\x0c\xddj%l\xdd\xde\xfb[\xfbZ\xad\xae#SR\xcfh\xfcSm%\xebE\xc87\x14\'#OY\xc4\xdf\xbc\xedM\x11]}i\xfc\x80z\xc7\x91\x9c?\x00\xe1\x9a\xf0p[<\x1d\x8cx\xf7@\t\xf4mf\xe1\xe8\x95\x99\xae\xcc\xabN\xad\xbe\x945neh<\xb8\x96\x99&\x95\x19<N\xe7\xa9\xf8Y\x86,\xe1\xe9l2i\x0f\x84\x95\xc7\x7f\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x03\x00\x8c$8\xafW\x0c\x00\x00'
```

Comment: It seems the loaded web page isn't UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: i edit. i see b'\x1\' example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte, while reading csv file in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659851/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8b-in-position-1-invalid)