# Error while reading a csv file by using csv module in python3

Tags: python-3.x

When I am trying to read a csv file I am getting this type of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Downloads/csvafa.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i in a:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

The code that i used:

```
import csv
with open('Book1.csv') as f:
    a=csv.reader(f)
    for i in a:
        print(i)
```

i even tried to change the encoding to latin1:

```
import csv
with open('Book1.csv',encoding='latin1') as f:
    a=csv.reader(f)
    for i in a:
        print(i)
```

After that i am getting this type of error  message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Downloads/csvafa.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i in a:
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

I am a beginner to python

Comment: Optionally resave your csv file as UTF-8.

Comment: Simon pls tell me how can i save my file as UTF-8..

Comment: Get a good text editor. For example sublime, and there should be a save with code page option. Select utf-8 codepage.

Answer (score 1):

This error is raised when we try to encode an invalid string. When Unicode string can’t be represented in this encoding (UTF-8), python raises a UnicodeEncodeError. You can try encoding: 'latin-1' or 'iso-8859-1'.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', encoding='ISO-8859–1')
```

It can also be that the data is compressed. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659851/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8b-in-position-1-invalid/44660123).

Answer (score 0):

I would try reading the file in `utf-8` enconding

another solution might be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659851/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8b-in-position-1-invalid/44660123)

> It's still most likely gzipped data. gzip's magic number is `0x1f 0x8b`, which is consistent with the `UnicodeDecodeError` you get.
>
> You could try decompressing the data on the fly:
>
> ```py
>   with open('destinations.csv', 'rb') as fd:
>        gzip_fd = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fd)
>       destinations = pd.read_csv(gzip_fd)
> ```