# error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 2: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I have a piece of code that does this:

```
def command(self, s, level=1):
        sub=subprocess.Popen(s, bufsize=0, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True);
        (out, err) = sub.communicate()
```

I see this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 2: invalid start byte

when I try to call the communicate method. The subprocess popen is reading as strings.

In a working condition it should return a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Show us how you are running this? By default subprocess.communicate() returns bytes, i.e., it doesn't try to decode them.

Comment: as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659851/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8b-in-position-1-invalid/44660123), I encountered this when a program running inside a Python `subprocess` spat out a block of compressed data to stdout amongst other normal text log lines

Answer (score 4):

With the `universal_newlines=True` parameter (which has a more readable alias `text=True` since Python 3.7), input and output are en-/decoded implicitly by Python.
You can tell Python which codec to use through the `encoding=` parameter.
If you don't specify a codec, the same defaults are used as in `io.TextIOWrapper`.

The default codec depends on a number of factors (OS, locale, Python version), but in your case it is apparently UTF-8.
However, your subprocess returns data which is *not* UTF-8 encoded.
So you need to refer to the documentation of that command:

- Does it return text in a Windows codepage, eg. CP-1252? Then specify this in the `encoding=` parameter to the `subprocess.Popen` call.
- Does it return text at all? If not, omit the `universal_newlines` parameter and process the binary data returned as `bytes` objects.