# ingesting gzip file from s3 to Postgres invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have a data.csv.gz file in S3 that contains special characters in some rows: [image: (]
the file also has no headers but I've created columns names in the Postgres table. When I check under metadata in S3, the type is **Content-Type: binary/octet-stream**

This is the error I'm seeing:

```
psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8b
```

This is what I'm doing that's creating the error:

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
'btr.Ats_20210304',
'ID,NAME,WEBSITE,TYPE,CATEGORY,SUB_CATEGORY,PARENT_ACCOUNT',
'(FORMAT csv, HEADER true, DELIMITER ",")',
'vdw-dev',
'date/hourly/data_0_0_0.csv.gz',
'us-east-1');
```

I've checked the postgres table's encoding using `SELECT pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'my_db';` and it's set to UTF8.

Comment: See here [Gzip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.FileFormats.gzip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation from AWS: [Importing an Amazon S3 compressed (gzip) file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.FileFormats.gzip)

You need to ensure that the S3 file has the following Amazon S3 metadata:

- Key: `Content-Encoding`
- Value: `gzip`